# Dependency injection for Moose classes

Tags: perl, dependency-injection, moose

I have a Moose class that needs to send requests of type `Foo::Request`. I need to make this dependency accessible from the outside, so that I can easily exchange the request implementation in tests. I came up with the following attribute:

```
has request_builder => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'CodeRef',
    default => sub {
        sub { Foo::Request->new(@_) }
    }
);
```

And then in code:

```
my $self = shift;
my $request = $self->request_builder->(path => …);
```

And in tests:

```
my $tested_class = …;
my $request = Test::MockObject->new;
$request->mock(…);
$tested_class->request_builder(sub { $request });
```

Is there a more simple / more idiomatic solution?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might be interested in the short blog entry by chromatic, which discusses the same technique: [You're Already Using Dependency Injection](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2011/08/youre-already-using-dependency-injection.html)

Comment: I like this solution and it is how I would solve it. The coderef gives you a lot of flexibility in how the object can be constructed.

Comment: @Mike: Thank you for the link. I’ve read the article some time ago and re-read it before posting this question. It’s a good reading, but does not address builders AFAIK. It’s just for “one-time” dependencies, not the ones that your class needs to build on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

How about applying a role dynamically in your tests with Moose::Util::apply_all_roles?  I have been wanting to use this for a while, but haven't had an excuse yet.  Here is how I think it would work.

First, modify your original attribute slightly:

```
package MyClientThing;
has request => (
    is      => 'rw',
    isa     => 'Foo::Request',
    builder => '_build_request',
);
sub _build_request { Foo::Request->new };
....
```

Then create a Test::RequestBuilder role:

```
package Test::RequestBuilder;
use Moose::Role;
use Test::Foo::Request; # this module could inherit from Foo::Request I guess?
sub _build_request { return Test::Foo::Request->new };
```

Meanwhile in 't/my_client_thing.t' you would write something like this:

```
use MyClientThing;
use Moose::Util qw( apply_all_roles );
use Test::More;

my $client  = MyClientThing->new;
apply_all_roles( $client, 'Test::RequestBuilder' );  

isa_ok $client->request, 'Test::Foo::Request';
```

See [Moose::Manual::Roles](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0202/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod#ADDING_A_ROLE_TO_AN_OBJECT_INSTANCE) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion, following the model in chromatic's article (comment above by Mike), is this:

In your class:

```
has request => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'CodeRef',
    default => sub {
        Foo::Request->new(@_)
    }
);
```

In your test:

```
my $request = Test::MockObject->new;
$request->mock(…);
my $tested_class = MyClass->new(request => $request, ...);
```

Does exactly what your code does, with the following refinements:

1. make the attribute read-only and set it in the constructor, if possible, for better encapsulation.
2. your `request` attribute is a ready-to-use object; no need to dereference the sub ref

Comment: Actually, if you must have a builder in the class implementation, your example is the right thing.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, exactly, I need a builder, therefore I can’t go with the simple object setter as presented in chromatic’s blog post. It really looks like the coderef builder is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this approach:

In your Moose class define an 'abstract' method called `make_request`. Then define two roles which implement `make_request` - one which calls `Foo::Request->new` and another one which calls `Test::MockObject->new`.

Example:

Your main class and the two roles:

```
package MainMooseClass;
use Moose;
...
# Note: this class requires a role that
# provides an implementation of 'make_request'


package MakeRequestWithFoo;
use Moose::Role;
use Foo::Request; # or require it
sub make_request { Foo::Request->new(...) }

package MakeRequestWithMock;
use Moose::Role;
use Test::MockRequest;  # or require it
sub make_request { Test::MockRequest->new(...) }
```

If you want to test your main class, mix it with the 'MakeRequestWithMock' role:

```
package TestVersionOfMainMooseClass;
use Moose;
extends 'MainMooseClass';
with 'MakeRequestWithMock';

package main;
my $test_object = TestVersionOfMainMooseClass->new(...);
```

If you want to use it with the Foo implementation of 'make_request', mix it in with the 'MakeRequestWithFoo' role.

Some advantages:

You will only load in modules that you need. For instance, the class `TestVersionOfMainMooseClass` will *not* load the module `Foo::Request`.

You can add data that is relevant/required by your implementation of `make_request` as instance members of your new class.  For example, your original approach of using a CODEREF can be implemented with this role:

```
package MakeRequestWithCodeRef;
use Moose::Role;
has request_builder => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'CodeRef',
  required => 1,
);
sub make_request { my $self = shift; $self->request_builder->(@_) };
```

To use this class you need to supply an initializer for `request_builder`, e.g.:

```
package Example;
use Moose;
extends 'MainMooseClass';
with 'MakeRequestWithCodeRef';

package main;
my $object = Example->new(request_builder => sub { ... });
```

As a final consideration, the roles you write might be usable with other classes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little old, but for anyone referring to this question now the requester could use a framework like [Bread::Board](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bread::Board).